# How can I access a parent client-side-collection from a child template in Meteor-Blaze?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, mongo-collection

I have a child template in which I want to be able to manipulate the parent's client-side-collection. The child template is a reusable component and can not have a global collection. Unluckily Template.parentData(n) doesn't work for me somehow. Accessing the collection via view isn't suitable either, because the level on which the parent collection lies is different from use case to use case (I want to give the context/index of the parent collection in the hierarchy dynamically to the child template). Here's an example of my code structure.

```
<template name="parentTemplate">
  <form id="accessGroupsPutForm">
    {{#let accessGroupSelected=accessGroupSelected}}
      ...
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="accessGroupsPutUsers" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">
          Access Rules
        </label>

        {{> childTemplate config=configAssignElements}}
      </div>
    {{/let}}
  </form>
```

Now I want to access a collection in the parent context from my child, possibly in the Template.childTemplate.onRendered() or .onCreated() function.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great atmosphere package that handles binding and many other things like this: https://atmospherejs.com/manuel/viewmodel. 
Using it, you can easily do `this.parent().runUpdateMethod(params)`